# can't install scikit-learn in python 3.10 for Windows 10?

Tags: python

it's all about **meson-python**:

> Run-time dependency openblas found: NO

> ....\scipy\meson.build:134:0: **ERROR**: Dependency "OpenBLAS" not
> found
>
> AttributeError: module 'mesonpy' has no attribute
> 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

[here](https://pypi.org/project/meson-python/):

> Platform Support - Windows :hammer: Does not support linking against
> libraries from the Meson project

how to solve this problem on Windows 10 python 3.10 ?? in order to install scikit-learn

p.s. though developers say [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#building-on-windows):

> Since version 0.21, scikit-learn automatically detects and uses the
> linear algebra library used by SciPy at runtime. Scikit-learn has
> therefore no build dependency on BLAS/LAPACK implementations such as
> OpenBlas, Atlas, Blis or MKL

Comment: is it possible somehow to [override a dependency](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files) in requirements.txt (or [Constraints File](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#constraints-files) )? how it could help?

Comment: installed VS_build_tools_2019 but it seems that cl_compiler does not help... [here](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/discussions/11205) is said about "a compiler capable of building fortran source code" -- what to do?

Comment: gfortran is already in GCC. Just add it to PATH

Answer (score 2):

helped with Python-3.7, but **NOT** with Python-3.10

```
pip install numpy mkl
pip install scipy
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir  scipy
pip install scikit-learn
```

SciPy should be installed first, then scikit-learn.
(still question in comments of initial Q - sorry to hurry with reply)

p.s.
in Python **3.10** still

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing qhull:

reason was while installing scikit-learn with

```
pip install --force-reinstall --prefer-binary scikit-learn
```

> ```
> Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started Preparing metadata
> (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
>
> exit code: 1 
> .... 
> OSError: [WinError 216] This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher  
> ...
> The Meson build system
> Version: 1.0.0 
> .....
> ERROR: Unhandled python OSError. This is probably not a Meson bug, but an issue with your build environment.
> ```

as I've understood, for my *Win10 32x* last stable version of Python is considered to be 3.7.(?3) to use scikit-learn

Comment: ... not a problem of *gfortran* as so as GCC in msys32/mingw32/bin (in PATH) comprises such compiler

Comment: **FOUND** comment as of Dec 28, 2022 [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16293): "Windows and MacOS are not yet fully supported, but that is actively being worked on."

Comment: [full doc](https://meson-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#editable-installs) of *meson-python* as dependency for scikit-learn

Comment: from [link](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/#files) out of [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/24604) - **NO** wheels for Windows 32x - for the latest scikit-learn 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem appeared to be in the localization of python installation -- reinstalled Python for **all users** (to Program Files folder), loaded WHEELS from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) & installed for python-3.10:

```
pip install c:\numpy-1.22.4+mkl-cp310-cp310-win32.whl
pip install  c:\scipy-1.7.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl
pip install c:\scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp310-cp310-win32.whl
```

also `pip install  pandas-1.4.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl`

for python-3.7 needed    `numpy-1.21.6+mkl-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`

important: !! **numpy + MKL** (Math Kernel Library) is needed

CHECKED:

```
##pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir numpy==1.21.6
import numpy
print(numpy.version.version)

##pip install  --force-reinstall c:\scipy-1.7.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl
import scipy
print(scipy.version.version)

##--force-reinstall --no-cache-dir c:\scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp310-cp310-win32.whl
import sklearn as sk
print(sk.__version__)
```

RESULT:

```
1.22.4
1.7.3
1.0.2
```

Comment: find Dependencies starting from link [here](https://piwheels.org/project/scikit-learn/) to PyPI page

Comment: if numpy-1.22.4+mkl is being explicitely reinstalled by the installer of other packages -- just reinstall it explicitly manually again !